# Google Pay ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX in Braintree payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, sandbox, braintree

I have implemented following sdk in my app
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/configuration/android/v2
for implementing google pay in my app. 
It is implementing successfully. But it is not working in sandbox/test environment. It requires live payment.

For making it sandbox/test I have refer following tutorial provided by google pay docs
https://developers.google.com/payments/tutorial

Still I'm not able to configure it with braintree sdk.

Can any one guide me how can I configure it in sandbox/test environment?

Comment: Can you update your question so that it meets [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Specifically, is there an error message you are seeing or expected behavior that is not happening? Can you include any code to help us replicate your issue?

Comment: I didn't get any error in production mode, it is working fine. But I want to test it with dummy cards, for that I can not find any way to do it. It is always giving me error of Transaction declined, Invalid payment method with dummy cards like 4111111111111111.

Comment: If you are using sandbox mode, then you have to provide the sandbox api credentials while configuring. The mode of payment should be `sandbox` then you can use these(https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/testing-go-live/php) cards for testing